# WordPress (on AWS ubuntu) database Fails "Connection refused in .. /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531"

Tags: wpdb

I'm trying to troubleshoot the issue I'm having. Every once in a while (seems to be every couple of nights, during overnight) the database fails to connect. Here is the error log:

```
PHP Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531
```

I can fix the problem temporarily by restarting the servers, but it's kinda annoying that this keeps happening. I just increased the max php memory limit to 256 to see if would do anything.

I am running on AWS Ubuntu server.

Comment: Anything in your databases error log?

Comment: @DavidSword Do you mind point it out how to access the database log? The log that I got that error from is the general WP log I believe

Comment: Your AWS a Bitnomi image? a vanilla Lamp stack on EC2? Or using AWS RDS? Or?

Comment: No idea. Sorry!

Comment: @DavidSword I think it's EC2

Comment: try `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: I had tried looked there before, but seems this directory is empty.

Comment: I tried to copy the whole `/var/log/` folder to my local machine, and couldn't copy a bunch of files with "no permission", even using sudo user